# Azure Data Factory dynamic content for Partition option (Copy activity)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to add dynamic content to the Partition option setting of the Copy data activity.
However, I am unsure what string to pass.

[image]

For example, passing a string literal does not work and results in the following error when previewing the data.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation use 'DynamicRange', 'PhysicalPartitionsOfTable', or 'None'.

[image]
[image]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server?tabs=data-factory#parallel-copy-from-sql-database